# How can I eliminate dead-zone on button with position relative? (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, button

I've recently noticed a problem with styled `<a>` and `<button>` tags which occurs with display block or inline-block, some amount of padding, and position relative to adjust the position when :active e.g.

```
a { display: inline-block; padding: 3px 6px; background: #aff; }
a:active { position: relative; top: 1px; left: 1px; }
```

The problem is a 1 pixel invisible box around the text where the click is not registered by the browser or by JavaScript, however the animation still occurs. This happens in (at least) Firefox and Chrome on Windows.

Here's a working example:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1186571/Test.htm

I've also tried using a margin instead of `position: relative;` and also tried setting `.active` with javascript instead of using `:active`.

Just to be clear: I am talking about a deadzone inside the link (the blue box in my example) but outside the bounding box of the text. Here's an image with the area I am talking about highlighted in dark blue:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1186571/example.png

Comment: I'm not really sure if I understand the problem completely, but just in case anyone would like to give a go at fixing this or taking a look at it more closely, I made a JSFiddle of the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZCkpE/4/ .

Comment: Try clicking exactly 1 pixel to the left of the "C" in the link, if you get it right the click won't register and JS won't add any text.

Comment: I can recreate this with both Firefox/Chrome (Windows). Odd. [Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BJGg9/) where the problem also occurs. [Also, it still happens here, with the `padding` removed.](http://jsfiddle.net/BJGg9/1/)

Comment: Attempted to resolve the issue using a `span` inside the `a` assuming the relative positioning was being problematic. This does not appear to be related `display:inline-block` or `position:relative`. Example page to exaggerate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/Vfc5r/

Comment: I don't think that's a related issue, you're clearly moving the link to the point where the mouse is no longer over it.

Comment: @peterjwest, I think it's related. It may be a hidden event targeting issue. If the `mousedown` is registered on the text, and the event target changes to the text's container for the `mouseup`, the `click` event may not be registered, which would cause what seems like a `1px` "box" around the text. It would be due to the fact that you're moving the text.

Comment: I'm going to agree with @zzzzBov on this one. In my testing, I've noticed that if you remove the `a:active` rule, but move your mouse between the `mousedown` and `mouseup`, the same bug occurs. This leads me to believe that it has to do with the event re-targeting from the `textNode` to the `a`, or vice-versa.

Comment: Oh yes, that makes total sense, I didn't realise that textNodes could capture events :O

Comment: @peterjwest, neither did I...I'd be curious as to whether this issue is duplicated on Opera, Safari, and IE, as well as FF, Chrome and Safari on Mac. It may just be a behind-the-scenes implementation issue as a common bug across browsers. the `onclick` method of event attachment causes the same behavior, so it's not a jQuery-specific issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the link is active you move it away, so you no longer click on the link. Using this will solve the problem:

```
a:active { 
    padding: 4px 5px 2px 7px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/ZCkpE/5/ (thanks for Kevin Gurney for creating the initial code)

**Update:**

It seems to a bug (or intended behaviour) in the browser. W3.org definition of click event:

> The click event occurs when the
>   pointing device button is clicked over
>   an element. A click is defined as a
>   mousedown and mouseup over the same
>   screen location. The sequence of these
>   events is:
>
> 1. mousedown
> 2. mouseup
> 3. click

You are obviously clicking on the same screen location. The problem is that the `mousedown` event is on the padding of the link, and the `mouseup` event is on the link (the text).

See http://jsfiddle.net/ZCkpE/8/ .

- If you mousedown on the **padding** move the mouse and mouseup on the **padding**, click event fires.
- If you mousedown on the **padding** move the mouse but now mouseup on the **text**, there is no click event.

It means that the padding and the text itself is not treated as the same element by the click event.

**Solution** without using too much "hack": make an overlaying div: http://jsfiddle.net/ZCkpE/13/ . Works in Chrome, Firefox. In IE it works if you click on the text. If you click on the padding the :active style is not activated.

Comment: Doesn't fix it. I'm talking about a deadzone just outside of the text, not outside the blue background.

Comment: Very nice solution, thanks! The only issue with that is that you can't select the text anymore, but that's something I can live with.

Comment: One more solution, using two divs instead of one to just cover the edges: http://jsfiddle.net/ZCkpE/17/

And ta-dah! You can select the text again. Anyway, the div/divs inside is a great solution, much better than the two links hack.

Comment: @Adam, just remember that block level elements are only acceptable with `a` elements in HTML5 (which your fiddle is), You'll need to use `span` elements if you're using an HTML4 doctype.

Comment: @Olli Etuaho, still has issues because you haven't covered *each* edge, it's a region around the **entire** text node where the overlap can occur, textnode->padding + padding->textnode

Comment: Ah, true, four divs are needed instead of two, just a small oversight. Gets a bit hackier, but still manageable: http://jsfiddle.net/ZCkpE/18/

Comment: Do you think it might be possible to use z-index to make a single div which is underneath for the purposes of highlighting, but on top in terms of event capture?

Comment: @peterjwest, I don't think it's possible to solve the click event and the text selection problem with only one div. Note that selecting the whole text works, only partial selection is problematic (in IE it works too).

Answer (score 1):

This is a terrible and ugly hack, but you could do something like this: instead of moving the actual link element or something inside it, move a separate link with the same text that you position at the same place. Of course, you'll also have to hide the actual link. It needs a lot of additional markup and the moving can be done only in JavaScript, but at least it can be done and works.

HTML:

```
<span class="link_container"><a href="#" class="main"><span>Click me</span></a> 
<span class="replacement"><a href="#" class="aux"><span>Click me</span></a></span></span>
```

CSS:

```
.link_container { display: inline-block; position: relative; }
a.main { display:inline-block; position: relative; z-index: 2; }
a.main span { position: relative; top: -1000px; }
.link_container span.replacement { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1; }
.link_container span.replacement span { display: inline-block; background-color: #fab; }
.link_container span.replacement span.offset { position: relative; left: 5px; top: 5px; }
```

JS that moves the text on each click:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("a").click(function() {
    $("span.replacement span").toggleClass("offset");
    $("p").text($("p").text()+" clicked!");
    return false; 
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vfc5r/36/

Tested in Chrome and IE8. Chrome reacts to the .main link and IE8 to the .aux link. Might be it doesn't actually fix things on the browsers that still react to the link that is moved, but is an improvement on the browsers that react to the link that is static.

Comment: I've updated it to work as intended, but yes that does fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/Vfc5r/37/ I'm holding out for a better fix though

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @zzzzBov and @Ryan Kinal, I've got a reasonable solution which is to bypass the click event on `a` tags and use mouseup instead:

```
$("a").click(false).mouseup(function() { window.location = $(this).attr('href'); });
```

A more complex (and more accurate) solution would be to recreate the click event with a jQuery plugin:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.newClick = function(fn) {
    if (fn === undefined) { 
      fn = function() { window.location = $(this).attr("href"); }; 
    }
    this.click(false);
    this.mousedown(function() {
      $(this).data("clicked", true);
    });
    this.mouseup(function(e) {
      var response = true;
      if ($(this).data("clicked")) {
        response = fn.call($(this), e);
      }
      $(this).data("clicked", false);
      return response; 
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.js").newClick(function(e) {
    $("p").text($("p").text() + " clicked!");
    return false;
  });
  $("a").newClick();
});
```

Here we bind any custom events first, then finally override the default click behaviour for all `a` tags. Here's a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZCkpE/16/